# Ability to create clustered indexes in ServiceStack/ORMLite codefirst

Tags: mysql, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I thought I saw it in ServiceStack 4 release notes, but search is failing me.  For ServiceStack, does  ORMLite have the ability to create a clustered index in code first?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
public class Poco
{
    [Index(Clustered=true)]
    public string Field1 { get; set; }

    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```